# Can 12 V, 0.7 Ah acid battery power two or three devices

Tags: batteries

I have bought a motorbike battery 12 V, with 0.7 Ah.

I want to power a router and the out fiber box, both devices require 12V.

1. Do I need a DC to DC model for that, or can I connect the jack directly to the battery?
2. Will the battery be able to power both devices?  If yes, how can I connect the cable to get 12 V for both?
3. Can I charge a laptop with the same battery?

Comment: Data sheet links for the following items needed: battery, router, fiber-box (?), jack (?), cable and, laptop. You also need to state how long all of these will need to be sustained if the battery is not being replenished from a charger.

Comment: Also please add a fuse as close as possible to the battery, can get nasty when shorted.

Comment: 0.7 Ah is very small. Are you sure? 7 Ah is common size. If small motorbike then 0.7 Ah isn’t unthinkable but your third question may be an issue with 0.7 Ah.

Answer (score 1):

A "12V" lead-acid battery is only *nominally* 12 Volts (i.e., "12V" in name only.) When it's being charged, the voltage can be almost (but not quite) as high as 15V. When it's fully charged, but off the charger, a bit above 13V. When it's deeply discharged, the voltage can be less than 11V. Electronic devices that are made for use in motor vehicles are designed to tolerate that range of voltages.

Your equipment, most likely was designed to work with external, *regulated,* 12V power bricks. Whether or not it will actually tolerate a wider range of voltages is something that you may only be able to learn by experimenting. You should be prepared to accept that a failed experiment could be fatal to the equipment.

---

P.S.; 700mAh sounds small compared to the devices that you intend to power. The Verizon Optical Network Terminal in my basement has a built-in standby battery that is ten times that size, and I think that is only intended to support it for a few hours.